# Regular Expression Regex for Format MMAYY - A is any alphabet and MM as month and YY as year

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to be used in the form.
The rule is simple, the format must be MMAYY.

**Example of valid MMAYY:**

```
01A21
12B20
01A22
```

**Example of invalid MMAYY:**

```
01121
22A21
```

I tried the below but it will check for MMYY only.

```
^0[1-9]|^(11)|^(12)[0-9][0-9]$
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is using alternation with incorrect grouping. Moreover you are not matching mont number `10` and you are also not matching a letter in the middle.

You may use this regex:

```sh
^(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])[A-Z][0-9]{2}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0ZPWi5/3)

**RegEx Demo**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])`: Match a 2 digit number for month number, of the form `01, 02, 03, ... 10, 11, 12`
- `[A-Z]`: Match an uppercase letter
- `[0-9]{2}`: Match 2 digits
- `$`: End

Answer (score 2):

I think your regex misses the letter.
This should do what you want:

```
(^0[1-9]|^(10)|^(11)|^(12))[A-Z]([0-9][0-9])$
```